# Best version Of blender?

Tags: installation

My laptop is core i5, 5th generation, 64gb RAM and SSD 256. I have installed the blender but it just showed me a white screen on startup. Even I try different versions 1 by 1. But there is the same issue. Only the candidate version is running but I can not explore more on it and do my project. Can you guide me on which version should I install and why it is happening?

Comment: Your laptop sounds more than capable of running the latest Blender.  Do you have the latest drivers installed for your graphics card?

Comment: yes, I check it. It is already updated. I tried different versions as I told you. One thing is the same. I check on the task manager. My system is not assigning a CPU to the blender. Even if only the blender is running. I also change the priority to real-time. But nothing happens.

Comment: Please check that your GPU fulfills the minimum requirements: https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Comment: My laptop does not have a dedicated graphics card. only has built-in AMD Radeon graphics.